# Docker не работает монтирование symbolink

Tags: linux, docker

Помогите разобраться:

Есть контейнер, в него смонтирован symbol link с хостовой системы. Symbol Link  ссылается на некую папку.

Когда я на хосте меняю symbol link на другую папку в контейнере ничего не происходит. В нем по прежнему видны файлы старой папки. На хосте при просмотре линка - все отрабатывает хорошо, изменения видны.

Линк меняю командой:

```
ln -sfn /opt/folder2 link1
```

Answer (score 1):

Симлинк и не должен работать. У приложения внутри докера нет доступа к тому на что указывает ссылка. Используйте [бинд-маунты вместо ссылок.](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/)

```
$ docker run -d \
  -it \
  --name devtest \
  --mount type=bind,source=/opt/folder2,target=/link1 \
  nginx:latest
```

или

```
"Mounts": [
    {
        "Type": "bind",
        "Source": "/opt/folder2",
        "Destination": "/link1",
        "Mode": "",
        "RW": true,
        "Propagation": "rprivate"
    }
],
```

Comment: их можно будет менять не перезапуская контейнер ?

Comment: Если очень хочется то можно